# Creating a video element from a blob

Tags: html, reactjs, video, jsx, filereader

I'm trying to create a video element from a blob in React. I've done this much. But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any mistake in this code?

```
loadBlob(blob, callback) {

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const result = event.target.result;     
      callback(result)
   }
}

createVideo(result) {
 this.setState({
    src:result
  })
}

loadBlob(blob, createVideo) /*Passing the blob and the callback in the click button click event*/
```

In the render I've

```
 <video>
   <source src = {this.state.src}/>
 </video>
```

The src is getting set in the video element when I checked with the inspector. 
When I console logged out the blob I'm getting this

```
Blob(231112) {size: 231112, type: "video/webm"}.
```

I'm wondering if this can be made to video using Filereader?

Comment: What happens? What doesn't happen? Have you looked at the resulting DOM in your browser's inspector to see that the src gets set?

Comment: Yeah the src is getting set in the video element when I checked with the inspector. When I console logged out the blob I'm getting this                                    
Blob(231112) {size: 231112, type: "video/webm"} . I'm wondering if this can be made to video using Filereader?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the discussion in the comments made me realize the issue.

You shouldn't use `data:` URIs for data that large; instead use [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).